# Prevent AFNetworking Reachability Status Getting Called at First Launch for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, reachability

I just want to know how to prevent my alert view from appearing everytime I open my application that's already connected to the internet. I'm using ARC if that helps.

This is the code I have in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method inside my AppDelegate:

```
__weak id myself = self; // to silence warning for retain cycle
_httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]];
    [_httpClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            {
                // Not reachable
                NSLog(@"Not connected to the internet");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Not connected to the internet" delegate:myself cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
                [alert show];

                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            {
                NSLog(@"Connected to the internet via WiFi");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Connected to the internet via WiFi" delegate:myself cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
                [alert show];

                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            {
                NSLog(@"Connected to the internet via WWAN");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Connected to the internet" delegate:myself cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
                [alert show];

                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling the UIAlertView at all when connected to the Internet? I guess I'm a bit confused why it's there if you don't want it.

Comment: I have this alertviews for now just to test for reachability especially when the network went down and came back up.  I would like to notify the user if he's connected to the network and present it in a subtle slide from above notification as required by the app I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @D80Buckeye: just don't pop an alert for reachability. It's completely unnecessary, and doesn't add anything to the user experience (it's not like the user can do anything to fix a lack of reachability like that). If anything, you could show a non-modal indication of network reachability.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do when the application got disconnected from the network and connects again. I'm just doing alertviews for now to test if reachability works. Even if I'm using a subtle indication for reachability, how can I prevent it from displaying at every launch of the app?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a global flag

```
static BOOL g_FirstTime = YES;
```

and check it before displaying alert view

```
if (g_FirstTime) {
    g_FirstTime = NO;
    break;
}

NSLog(@"Connected to the internet via WiFi");
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Connected to the internet via WiFi" delegate:myself cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
[alert show];
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the scope of your project it's hard to make a solid suggestion. My whole-hearted suggestion is that you do NOT want to do a pop-up every time the end user bounces back on the network. If you have code implemented that is reliably detecting a refreshed network connection, if I were you, I would put some sort of subtle (but obvious) on-screen indicator like a small icon/image or maybe even a UILabel that says "connected" or "disconnected" or whatever verbiage works for you. As others have suggested I would completely steer clear of instantiating a pop-up of any sort for that alert.

Regarding the code itself - get very familiar with [View Controller Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10) and [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). Between those two documents you can properly map out how to detect and react to when your app comes in and out of the background state, when it launches, when it becomes active, when your views appear/load, etc. Combine those methods & calls with some global state-driven variables and you should be well on your way.

Bottom line is you want to get familiar with those app state documents as well as `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#> name:<#(NSString *)#> object:<#(id)#>]`

Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually the old version of my project uses NSNotificationCenter and Reachability from Tony Million and it works just like I wanted to. I tried doing that too in AFNetworking's reachability and it doesn't have the same behavior wherein when the app starts, the reachability flag doesn't get called, only when it resumes from being disconnected from the network.

Comment: What are you using as a trigger to search for reachability, though? those methods will only be called when you call them - they aren't listeners.